# How to make grouped horizontal bar plot with changed colors and several sub-plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, bar-chart, subplot

In Python, I want to make a horizontal bar plot with three sub-plots where each panel has five groups of four bars, while also changing the automatic color of the bars.

Building on the code below which is inspired by this [guidance here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.barh.html), how could I a) change colors of the bars in each group (e.g. to dark blue, light blue, dark purple, light purple), and b) make a plot that has three of these panels, not just one (e.g. can it be combined with code that I usually use for several subplots
`fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3)`?

```
`speed = [40, 48, 52, 69, 88]
lifespan = [70, 1.5, 25, 12, 28]
height = [35, 5, 18, 17, 43]
width = [40, 18, 35, 37, 15]
index = ['elephant', 'rabbit', 'giraffe', 'coyote', 'horse']
df = pd.DataFrame({'speed': speed, 'lifespan': lifespan, 'height': height, 'width': width}, index=index)
ax = df.plot.barh()`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define colours within `df.plot.barh()` using a dict of {column_name:color_code},

```
ax = df.plot.barh(color={"speed": "#08519c", "lifespan": "#6baed6","height":'#54278f',"width":'#bcbddc'})
```

or a list of colours,

```
ax = df.plot.barh(color=["#08519c", "#6baed6",'#54278f','#bcbddc'])
```

For multiple panels, assign plots to different axes, for example,

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3)
for i in range(3):
    df_subset = ...
    axes[i] = df_subset.plot.barh(color={"speed": "#08519c", "lifespan": "#6baed6","height":'#54278f',"width":'#bcbddc'})
```